# Simultaneous Navbar index page change

Tags: flutter, dart

sorry for my english I am a French baguette

Here is my question, I was wondering how I could switch pages while moving my index in the NavBar I have already tried the solution above but my crash after a few seconds I wonder why?

**Here is the code of my homepage**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/views/screenmaps_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/views/screenussers_views.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _selectedItemIndex = 0;
  int setPageIndex = 0;

  final pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    PageMaps(),
    userpage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pages[setPageIndex], //the line that makes me crash my application
      //backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: [
          newNavBarItem(Icons.home_outlined, 0),
          newNavBarItem(Icons.map_outlined, 1),
          newNavBarItem(Icons.home, 2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget newNavBarItem(IconData icon, int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedItemIndex = index;
          setPageIndex = index;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
          height: 70,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
          decoration: index == _selectedItemIndex
              ? BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(width: 4, color: Color(0xff238ADC)),
                  ),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                    Color(0xff7EC1F6).withOpacity(0.3),
                    Color(0xff7EC1F6).withOpacity(0.015)
                  ], begin: Alignment.bottomCenter, end: Alignment.topCenter),
                )
              : BoxDecoration(),
          child: Icon(icon,
              color:
                  index == _selectedItemIndex ? Colors.black : Colors.black)),
    );
  }
}
```

I initialized a variable "setPageIndex" with the value of the index of the navbar to associate it with the body to display but without success the report of the crash is lower

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pages[setPageIndex], //the line that makes me crash my application
      //backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: [
          newNavBarItem(Icons.home_outlined, 0),
          newNavBarItem(Icons.map_outlined, 1),
          newNavBarItem(Icons.home, 2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**here is the error from errors_path.dart**

```
@pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNew")
  external static _doThrowNew(
      int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNewSource")
  external static _doThrowNewSource(
      String failedAssertion, int line, int column, Object? message);
```

**and here is the err of my debug console**

```
#24     DiagnosticsNode.toString
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1706
#25     Diagnosticable.toString.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3168
#26     Diagnosticable.toString
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3170
#27     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:853:19)
#28     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4785
#29     StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4928
#30     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4477
#31     ComponentElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4735
#32     StatefulElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4919
#33     ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4729
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#40     Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3790
#41     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3540
#42     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4780
#43     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4477
2
...
...     Normal element mounting (21 frames)
#4821   Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3790
#4822   Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3540
#4823   RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1198
#4824   RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1167
#4825   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1112
#4826   BuildOwner.buildScope
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2600
#4827   RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1111
#4828   WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:944
#4829   WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:924
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

If things seem special to you in the code, I'm starting by the way, tell me if something is wrong :)

and thank you for reading my threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are adding the `HomeScreen` again in `pages` array of the navbar, while it's already the screen having the navbar, so your pages should be:

```
final pages = [
  AnotherHomePage(),
  PageMaps(),
  userpage(),
];
```